# Is there a way of obtaining 95% confidence intervals for the bias-corrected estimate of the c statistic?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, logistic

I ran a binary logistic regression and then used the boostrap internal validation procedure, implemented in Frank Harrel's RMS package in R. I saw a couple of studies having used boostrap validation and then given the 95%CI of their optimism corrected c-index. I was wondering if there was a way to obtain it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you add a link to any of those studies?

Comment: @Jim Thanks! Here's one article I found: https://bit.ly/2Zws1WT I think you should be able to access it for free.